# Geoserver : FAIL context path doesn't start

Tags: geoserver, apache, tomcat

I've been manipulating Geoserver for some time without any problem.

Today,when I start Apache Tomcat , Geoserver doesn't start.

I get this error message :

```
" FAIL - Application at context path /Geoserver could not be started"
```

I don't know what seems to be the problem.
Please help me with this issue
ᐧ

Comment: that usually happens to me when I add an unsupported with that version jar(plugin)

Comment: Thanks @elasticrash for you reply. I didn't quite understand what you mean by unsupported, Geoserver was running great for weeks , but today it couldn't start.

Comment: It did happen with me the same a few weeks ago. My problem was the geowebcash reached the allowed limit for the generated tiles and after that the geoserver couldn't set up. I tried to change the limit in one of the config file but no success. I had to delete some of the genereated tiles manually and after that it worked perfectly.

Comment: @TamasKosa , thank you for the tip. Could you please let me know where in the geoserver folder I need to delete exactly? i'm complete newbie  at this .I'd be thankful.

Comment: @ImaneKtb you can find in ../geoserver/gwc/yourlayersfolder

Comment: @ImaneKtb well geoserver supports a number of different plugins depending its version (like wps or printing) if someone happens to add an unsupported one it gives that generic error. If you didn't mess with the installation folder...then its something entirely else

Comment: @elasticrash thank you for helping. However, I didn't mess with the installation folder.

Answer (score 2):

@ImaneKtb you can find in ../geoserver/gwc/yourlayersfolder. Just delete one of you "yourlayersfolder". The full path of the geoserver it depend on your type of install (Windows, Linux, Geoserver installer, Boundless installer etc.) It helped to me, but it does'nt mean it will help in your case. The error looks kind of generic error. But anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for help . But delecting gwc files didn't solve the issue. Now, I tried this : I replaced  the Geoserver folder that couldn't start and generated another one by executing the war .Then I replaced the 'data' repository by the previews one that had all my data .

When I run Apache, Geoserver starts, however when I see that all my previews layers aren't active . When I try to   republish them . I get this error :  "Failed to load attribute list, internal error is: null"

Comment: Is the store enabled?

Comment: Yes both the workspace and the data store are activated,only when trying to publish the layers I get this error .

Comment: Are you sure permissions are set correctly on the data folder, such that the tomcat user can create folders.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced a situation like this.

Apparently everything was "ok" with my Tomcat installation, and I also seemed to place the `.war` file properly (as I could see its folder being created on the `/webapps` directory).

What helped me find the answer was to **check the Tomcat logs**; you can see them in the `/tomcat/logs` directory (specifically the `catalina.out` file).

My problem was that the version of Geoserver I was using (2.13.0) **requires Java 8 to run**, and I was using Java 7. I suggest you **check your logs, and also the requirements of your Geoserver version**. Changing my configuration to use Java 8 solved the problem and I was able to start and access my webservice successfully.